# EndEdit Clearing Data Before Update

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form for a case tracking program. Inserting a new record is working correctly. When changing data, the values for certain comboBoxes are  getting cleared when I issue the EndEdit. So, when the update is issued, the values are not saved.

R2 is a DataRow. 
Column A is an integer, populated from the comboBox items collection
Column B is an integer, populated from the comboBox items collection
Column C is a string, populated from a DataSource
Column D is a string, text box is bound to a column in the table

ComboBoxes are all bound to the SelectedValue.

When I make a change to  comboBox3, all the values remain the same, except the one that I have changed. Until the EndEdit is executed. Then the value for comboBox2 is set to empty, and the value is lost after the Update is executed.

I don't understand why this is happening. I have set up similar forms the same way without issue. So, I must be missing something, but I don't know what. Any nudges in the right direction much appreciated.

```
        R2["A"]    = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        R2["B"]    = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
        R2["C"]    = comboBox3.Text;
        R2["D"]    = textBox12.Text;

        this.Validate();
        this.tblLowDataBindingSource.EndEdit();
        T2.Update(this.dOLUEDataSet.tblLowData);
```